# sfdx force:apex:log:tail command is not working anymore

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Can anyone pls advise if the tailing the log option has been removed in any recent upgrade  of SFDX cli. This is  used to work earlier, recently I am seeing not  working anymore. Thought ?

sfdx --version sfdx-cli/7.133.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.13.1

sfdx force:apex:log:tail
›   Warning: force:apex:log:tail is not a sfdx command.

But the documentation says  this should support.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version. It may have been a bug in that particular version of the build. Unfortunately, I don't have a `darwin` machine to test with, but it's working on `sfdx-cli/7.133.0 win32-x86 node-v14.17.0` as well as `sfdx-cli/7.134.0 win32-x86 node-v14.17.0`.